# Clear online Shivisi

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, shemos-sacred-names, prayer-book, pictures

Where can I find a nice clear online (not a scan or photo of some old document) [*Shivisi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiviti) for printing?

[image: Shivisi with Hebrew text in the form of a menorah]

Comment: <http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-S81KcmK7naw/VltVm_yjfZI/AAAAAAAALw8/ZJArKK55rVQ/s1600/67.png>, it's in Wellisch

Comment: If I remember good, you have found yourself in office a possibility to write Shem Hashem with yod ke vav ke and adnut inside the he.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Why is that not a proper answer?

Comment: @kouty A Shivisi is more than just the combined name. It is various texts around a central Menora shaped Lamnatzeach Binginos Mizmor Shir with the actual Shivisi Hashem above.

Comment: OK sorry for the amaratsut.

Comment: Just remember how holy these are. Aruch Hashulchan warned against shuls having them without glass whereupon they got soiled from the oil and wax of the lights.

Comment: @user6591, how are they any holier than anything else below a mezuzah with the tetragrammaton written on it?

Comment: @Noach I'm not sure what you mean by below a mezuzah

Comment: @user6591, something which doesn't have the same level of kedusha as a sta"m product, eg a handwritten siddur, Ketoret, and, of course, a Shiviti

Comment: @Noach I don't recall exactly what he wrote. I think it had something to do with kabbala. But even disregarding that it is still a sheim hashem. We must be careful with it. Not just print one up cause its easily found online and leave it on the table for the kids to spill juice on. That's all.

Comment: @user6591, what's the siman? Also, how could a Shiviti be holier than a Torah, which we most certainly do **not** put behind glass when it's in use?

Comment: @Noach I've been trying to locate it. I'm having difficulty. Its not holier than a seffer torah. It was just placed where it would commonly get soiled. Hence his warning. I'm just passing the message along that printing this up to keep in your pocket and read while drinking a coffee would be unwise. Same with printing up a kitoret. For whoever reads this post in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-S81KcmK7naw/VltVm_yjfZI/AAAAAAAALw8/ZJArKK55rVQ/s1600/67.png%3E) Shiviti after a quick Google Images search.

[image: Shivisi PNG with clear packground]

Comment: @Adám, you're welcome! I'm glad to know that your orening was improved.